# Magento 2.1.7: after install no admin directory: "Launch Mangento Admin" > nothing

Tags: magento

I can't see that this problem has arisen here before hence>
For the first time I downloaded Magento ver 2.1.7 to XAMMP, the installation went perfectly and ended with the "Launch Mangento Admin" button.  I pressed the button and a new browser appeared then nothing happened (went and made tea still just a blank screen), strangely there isn't even an admin directory in the document folder to examine. Asked Google: nothing (tried Yahoo too)... your turn?

Comment: After stepping through the code I got: "Project raised exception class Magento\Framework\Exeption\NoSuchEntityExeption with message "Requested store not found" at StoreRepository.php, line 76

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I agree this question stands a better chance in Magento so I've transferred the question there. Thanks.
It is a programming problem, it's not off topic, it's just in the incorrect place...

Comment: What makes this a programming question?